# [autoware.auto] ray_ground_filter publishing 0 filled point cloud without error

Tags: ros2, lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the ray_ground_filter from Autoware.auto with a VLP-32C lidar. I have sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data from the lidar entering that node and being processed without any reported errors. However, the output messages for both ground and non-ground contain points clouds where all data is set to 0. I believe this occurs because the resize message call is filling in only zeros for the entire data array, but I'm not sure why the original data is being lost. Since there don't appear to be any errors or warnings from the node, what could be the cause of this behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394716/%5Bautoware.auto%5D-ray_ground_filter-publishing-0-filled-point-cloud-without-error/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2022-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems I had an outdated build. The solution was the same as the fix for this similar issue https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/1360

---

Originally posted by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) with karma: 268 on 2022-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0